# Present or Present Perfect in this sentence

Tags: tense, present-perfect

> To illustrate this, suppose we want to eliminate the navigation bar from the page sidebar. We may create a rule in which the link density feature (**is or has been ?**) employed to distinguish such a part. However, when this rule (**is or is being ?**) applied to the page, all such elements are removed regardless of their locations, even if they are within the main content (e.g. Table of Contents).

When we want to say for example *we may create or want to create X in which Y (is or has been or was) used for this purpose*?

Example from web:

> Peaceable school programs seek to create schools in which conflict resolution has been integrated at every level.

Answer (score 1):

In your "peaceable school programs" example, the *resolution* undergoes integration before the *school* can be considered *created*.  Is it the same with employing your *link density feature* with respect to *rule creation*?  In other words, when you "*create a rule*", how is the "*feature*" employed?  Prior to rule creation or eventually, when the rule is processed?

If your mechanism (or process) employs the "*density feature*" before the rule is created, then Present Perfect is OK.  If the employment of the "*density feature*" is part of the rule itself, then you should use Present Indefinite.

As to your second emphasis, it does not really matter which you use, and perhaps Present Indefinite is simpler to understand, although Continuous is just as acceptable.

Comment: The link density feature is used in the rule when we create the rule (it is part of the rule), but a use can decide to use this feature before going to create a rule. also in the school example it is not obvious that the resolution has been occurred prior the creation, they all seem some imaginary constructions.

Comment: Still unclear about the feature and the rule.  "But a *use* can decide..." - did you mean "a use**r**"?  (assuming "a user")  If that feature is used before creating the rule, what's the relationship between the rule and the feature?

Comment: Thank you, I think I almost got what you mean, if instead of "create" we use "use", then we could say "*to use a rule in which the link density has been employed....*"

Comment: In light of this I think Present Indefinite is actually better.